# Remove XML Parent Elements Based on Condition of Child Element - Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, automation, metadata

I am attempting to remove parent XML elements based on the text of specific child elements containing values of "nan".  The input XML contains namespaces which is making this trickier than expected and I can remove select child elements individually, but not the associated/adjacent parent elements.  I am only able to remove the "nan" value associated with the gam:String element, but I would like to remove all child elements with "nan" text values and their associated parent elements.

Below is the script I am using, along with the input and (desired) output XMLs....any assistance is most appreciated!

The Script:

```
from lxml import etree
import os 

path = "C:\\users\\mdl518\\Desktop\\"

### Removing "Nan" Values
tree = etree.parse(os.path.join(path,"metadata_info.xml"))

for elem in tree_2.findall('.//{http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/gam/1.0}String'):
   if elem.text=='nan':
     parent = elem.getparent()
     parent.remove(elem)
    
with open(".//metadata_output.xml","wb") as f:
    f.write(etree.tostring(tree_2, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8')) ## Removes elements with "nan" values
```

Input XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<nas:metadata xmlns:nas="http://www.arcgis.com/schema/nas/base"   
xmlns:mcc="http://standards.org/iso/19115/-3/mcc/1.0"    
xmlns:mdl="http://standards.org/iso/19115/-3/mdl/1.0" 
xmlns:mnl="http://standards.org/iso/19115/-3/mnl/1.0">
xmlns:lan="http://standards.org/iso/19115/-3/lan/1.0">
xmlns:lis="http://standards.org/iso/19115/-3/lis/1.0">
xmlns:gam="http://standards.org/iso/19115/-3/gam/1.0">
  <mdl:metadataIdentifier>
    <mcc:MD_Identifier>
      <mnl:name>
        <mnl:type>
          <gam:String>The Metadata File</gam:String>
        </mnl:type>
        <mnl:description>
          <mcc:listing codeList="http://arcgis.com/codelist/ScopeCode" codeListValue="dataset"</mcc:listing>
        </mnl:description>
      </mnl:name>
      <mnl:address>
        <mnl:defaultLocale>
          <lan:location>nan</lan:location>
        </mnl:defaultLocale>
      </mnl:address>
      <lan:language>
        <lan:type>
          <lis:name>English</lis:name>
        </lan:type>
       </lan:language>
     </mcc:MD_Identifier>
     <mcc:contactInfo>
       <mdl:POC>
         <mnl:name>
           <lis:person>Tom</lis:person>
         </mnl:name>
         <mnl:age>
           <gam:String>nan</gam:String>
         </mnl:age>
         <mnl:status>
           <lis:employment>nan</lis:employment>
         </mnl:status>
       </mdl:POC>
     </mcc:contactInfo>
   </mdl:metadataIdentifier>
 </nas:metadata>
```

Output XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<nas:metadata xmlns:nas="http://www.arcgis.com/schema/nas/base"   
xmlns:mcc="http://standards.org/iso/19115/-3/mcc/1.0"    
xmlns:mdl="http://standards.org/iso/19115/-3/mdl/1.0" 
xmlns:mnl="http://standards.org/iso/19115/-3/mnl/1.0">
xmlns:lan="http://standards.org/iso/19115/-3/lan/1.0">
xmlns:lis="http://standards.org/iso/19115/-3/lis/1.0">
xmlns:gam="http://standards.org/iso/19115/-3/gam/1.0">
  <mdl:metadataIdentifier>
    <mcc:MD_Identifier>
      <mnl:name>
        <mnl:type>
          <gam:String>The Metadata File</gam:String>
        </mnl:type>
        <mnl:description>
          <mcc:listing codeList="http://arcgis.com/codelist/ScopeCode" codeListValue="dataset"</mcc:listing>
        </mnl:description>
      </mnl:name>
      <lan:language>
        <lan:type>
          <lis:name>English</lis:name>
        </lan:type>
       </lan:language>
     </mcc:MD_Identifier>
     <mcc:contactInfo>
       <mdl:POC>
         <mnl:name>
           <lis:person>Tom</lis:person>
         </mnl:name>
       </mdl:POC>
     </mcc:contactInfo>
   </mdl:metadataIdentifier>
 </nas:metadata>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to be done in two stages: first remove all nodes with `nan` text nodes and then go over the empty nodes created by the first step and remove them as well:

```
#step 1 - remove nan nodes
for n in tree.xpath('//*[.="nan"]'):
    n.getparent().remove(n)]

#step 2 - select empty nodes and remove them as well
empty = [e for e in doc.xpath('//*[not(normalize-space())]')]

for emp in empty:
    try:
        emp.getparent().remove(emp)
    #one nested empty node is created by the first step; this step removes both nodes so try/except is necessary:
    except:
        continue
print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())
```

This should get you your desired output.

Comment: Thanks, @Jack, your solution works brilliantly!  However, for some reason the script also removes XML elements (and their parent elements) with visible attributes.  This was not included in the original input XML above, as I didn't think it would make a difference, but when I do "print(elem.text)" for all elements it shows these element text values as "None".  Is there a suggested workaround for this?  I added an example of this in the updated Input XML, and have already confirmed your solution as the correct answer - Thanks again!

Comment: @mdl518 Let me take a look.

Comment: @mdl518 Sorry about the delay. I couldn't replicate the issue because the new xml you posted is not well formed (run it through an XML validator and you'll see the errors). More specifically, once you fix that, you should post the issue as a new question as per SO policy. I'll be happy to take another look.

Comment: Hey, @Jack, thanks for your feedback.  I will take another look at the XML, I basically need to preserve the XML elements which can be considered as empty branches with attributes only (e.g. "codeList") and no values.  I will try to come up with a workaround via new logic, or just post in a new Q&A...your insights are most appreciated!